# Determine if a subprocess reads from stdin

Tags: python, subprocess, stdin, popen

I have a python script that starts other processes via `subprocess.run(...)`. Usually such a process runs automatically without reading from stdin. However, in the case of an error the processes waits for user input. I want detect such a situation from the calling python script and then e.g. kill that process. How could I achieve this?

(My idea was to create a file-like object which raises an Exception when its `.read()` method is called and pass it to `subprocess.Popen(...)` as a "bait" for the stdin kwarg. However this seems somehow ugly because some `fileno` needed to be faked.)

Comment: Not sure if this is possible with the subprocess module. I needed something similar a few days ago and settled for [pexpect](https://pypi.org/project/pexpect/) There you can define regexes/strings to basically wait for and when that comes up you can handle it as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass an empty file, e.g. `subprocess.DEVNULL`. A process which waits for standard input will get an EOF signalled if it tries reading from such a file.